# How do I access data for each pixel within an image and store it in an array in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I want to create an array in Earth Engine that is composed of the NDVI data of each pixel in the image. Below is the code that calculates the NDVI of each pixel in the ROI (a region). I can store the data for a specified pixel (check the code below the "Extract the data" comment) in a variable(dataN), but I am unable to store the data for each pixel in the region in an array.

```
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA"),
roi = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([74.47821320074036, 31.556778358715253]);

var rgb_vis = {min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']};
var filtered = L8.filterDate('2015-09-01', '2015-10-30').filterBounds(roi);
var image = ee.Image(filtered.first());
var red = image.select('B4');var nir = image.select('B5');

var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)); //layer from which I want to access the individual pixel data from

Map.addLayer(image, rgb_vis, 'RGB');
Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min: 0, max: 1}, 'NDVI');

// Extract the data
var data = ndvi
.select("B5")
.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), roi, 10)
.get("B5")

// Convert to Number for further use
var dataN = ee.Number(data)

// Show data
print(dataN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your **roi** object is a point but let's say it was a polygon or a set of points stored as a **featureCollection** object then you could do it as

```
var ndvi_array = ndvi.sampleRegions({
  collection:roi,
  scale:30 //the scale of image 'ndvi' should go here. i put 30 since its landsat
}).aggregate_array("B5"); //'B5' since that is the name of your band
```

This will give you an array of pixels sampled at the same same scale as the image within the region roi which should include all the pixels. However, I do suggest **against** this practice if you are going to sample over a polygon or polygons. That would be too resource intensive and also remember you can not display an array of more than 5000 elements on the console.

Comment: Thank you, Nishanta! This works well for a specified region that is not too big. Also yes, my ROI was a point, I changed that to a pixel, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I agree with the part where you said that this gets resource-intensive when one tries to sample it over a large region. Is there any other approach for storing the NDVI for each pixel in an image? I have to do this because I have to implement Dynamic Time Warping in Earth Engine for a city. Any help will be appreciated. Again, thank you for your initial answer!